# How to print digits which are greater than 7 digits in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to print the digits which is greater than 7 digits in python3?

```
 import re
 in_put = ["741014145453  3","4 A4101414545"]
 for i in in_put:
    output = re.findall(r"\D(\d{5+})\D", in_put)
    print(output)

    output = "741014145453","A4101414545"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would search for `\b\w*\d{7,}\w*\b`:

```
in_put = ["741014145453  3","4 A4101414545"]
for i in in_put:
    output = re.findall(r'\b\w*\d{7,}\w*\b', i)
    print(output)

['741014145453']
['A4101414545']
```

The pattern used just says to find 7 or more digit characters, possibly inside a larger word, separated by word boundaries.

Comment: `input` is a builtin function in Python 3. Shouldn't be using it as variable name

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want to find things that is more than 7 characters so you can us if statement instead of using regex.

```
in_put = ["741014145453  3","4 A4101414545"]
new_input = []
for item in in_put:
    new_input.extend(item.split())

for all in new_input:
   if len(all) > 7 :
        print (all)
```

OUTPUT :

```
741014145453
A4101414545
```

Comment: I updated @suba .My answer is one of option without using regex

Comment: I like not using regex whenever possible, but this would seem to match _any_ string with a length greater than 7, even something like `abcdefgh`, which has no digits.

Comment: You are right . I suppose list elements are  digits number so I posted like above @TimBiegeleisen